# Automatically trigger click on page load using data attribute - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to trigger a click on page load based on the data attribute, in this case data-filter. I have the value of the attribute saved in local storage. I retrieve it, but I'm not sure how I target the particular list item which has that attribute.

For example, how do I target   if the local storage returns .portfolio-category-1?

Thanks in advance

```js
/* on click do this */
$(".edgtf-pl-filter").click(function() {
  var isFilter = $(this).data("filter");
  localStorage.setItem('pod-filter', isFilter);
  alert(isFilter);
});


/* On page load, do this */
var isFilterRet = localStorage.getItem('pod-filter');
setTimeout(function() {
  $(".edgtf-pl-filter").trigger('click');
}, 10);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="edgtf-pl-filter" data-filter="">
    <span>all</span>
  </li>
  <li class="edgtf-pl-filter" data-filter=".portfolio-category-1">
    <span>Categroy 1</span>
  </li>
  <li class="edgtf-pl-filter" data-filter=".portfolio-category-2">
    <span>Category 2</span>
  </li>
  <li class="edgtf-pl-filter" data-filter=".portfolio-category-3">
    <span>Category 3</span>
  </li>
  <li class="edgtf-pl-filter" data-filter=".portfolio-category-4">
    <span>Category 4</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I correct understand what do you what. You just what to trigger on element which name/class is stored in variable isFilterRet?

Try this:

```
var isFilterRet = localStorage.getItem('pod-filter');
setTimeout(function() {
    if (isFilterRet){
        $(isFilterRet).trigger('click');
    }
},10);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

I have added a `.each()` function to check all `.edgtf-pl-filter` and identify the element with the `localStorage` and trigger a `click()` to it.

*I have removed the `setTimeout()` function as it is not required*

```js
/* on click do this */
$(".edgtf-pl-filter").click(function() {
  var isFilter = $(this).data("filter");
  localStorage.setItem('pod-filter', isFilter);
  alert(isFilter);
});


/* On page load, do this */
var isFilterRet = localStorage.getItem('pod-filter');
$(".edgtf-pl-filter").each(function() {
  var atrFil = $(this).data("filter");
  if (atrFil == isFilterRet) {
    $(this).trigger('click');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="edgtf-pl-filter" data-filter="">
    <span>all</span>
  </li>
  <li class="edgtf-pl-filter" data-filter=".portfolio-category-1">
    <span>Categroy 1</span>
  </li>
  <li class="edgtf-pl-filter" data-filter=".portfolio-category-2">
    <span>Category 2</span>
  </li>
  <li class="edgtf-pl-filter" data-filter=".portfolio-category-3">
    <span>Category 3</span>
  </li>
  <li class="edgtf-pl-filter" data-filter=".portfolio-category-4">
    <span>Category 4</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jithinrajpr7/05moezyw/) to check it's working fine.**

Hope this was helpful for you.